# Loop to 100 then change change row x times

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to create a vba loop that loops to 100 then continues value 101 at row 1 on the next column.

Column A data would have 1-100, B = 101-200, C = 201-300 etc.,

This is some code I got online and I am trying to modify it.

```
Sub exa()
    Dim CB          As CommandBar
    Dim ctl         As CommandBarButton
    Dim strCBName   As String
    Dim wbTemp      As Workbook
    Dim wks         As Worksheet
    Dim rngInput    As Range
    Dim i           As Long

    Set CB = CommandBars.Add(Position:=msoBarPopup, MenuBar:=False, Temporary:=True)
    Set ctl = CB.Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlButton, Temporary:=True)
    strCBName = CB.Name

    'Set wbTemp = Workbooks.Add(xlWBATWorksheet)
    'Set wks = wbTemp.Worksheets(1)
    Set wks = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
    Set rngInput = wks.Range("A:A")

    rngInput.Offset(, -1).ColumnWidth = 6.5
    rngInput.ColumnWidth = 6.5
    rngInput.HorizontalAlignment = xlRight

    For i = 1 To 100
        ctl.FaceId = i
        ctl.CopyFace
        rngInput.Cells(i).PasteSpecial
        rngInput.Cells(i).Value = i
    Next

    rngInput.Cells(1).Select

    On Error Resume Next
    Set CB = CommandBars(strCBName)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If Not CB Is Nothing Then
        CB.Delete
    Else
        MsgBox "no toolbar!", 0, vbNullString
    End If
End Sub
```

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you can try this:

```
Sub exa()
    Dim CB          As CommandBar
    Dim ctl         As CommandBarButton
    Dim strCBName   As String
    Dim wbTemp      As Workbook
    Dim wks         As Worksheet
    Dim rngInput    As Range
    Dim i           As Long

    Set CB = CommandBars.Add(Position:=msoBarPopup, MenuBar:=False, Temporary:=True)
    Set ctl = CB.Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlButton, Temporary:=True)
    strCBName = CB.Name

    Set wks = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    Dim Number As Integer
    Dim FaceNumber As Integer
    Number = 1
    'Only doing the first 5 columns, change the 5 to what ever number you want to get the number of columns desired
    For x = 1 To 5
    'Moved the setting of the range into the first FOR loop to assign the column
    Set rngInput = wks.Range(wks.Cells(1, x), wks.Cells(100, x))
    'This will move down each row
        For i = 1 To 100
        'This updates the Face that you are producing so that it will not repeat the same 100 every column
            If x > 1 Then
                If i > 1 Then
                    FaceNumber = FaceNumber + 1
                Else
                    FaceNumber = 100 * x - 99
                End If
            Else
                FaceNumber = i
            End If
            ctl.FaceId = FaceNumber
            ctl.CopyFace
            rngInput.Cells(i).PasteSpecial
            rngInput.Cells(i).Value = FaceNumber
        Next i
    Next x

    rngInput.Cells(1).Select

    On Error Resume Next
    Set CB = CommandBars(strCBName)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If Not CB Is Nothing Then
        CB.Delete
    Else
        MsgBox "no toolbar!", 0, vbNullString
    End If
End Sub
```

I've added comments to help you understand the updates that I made.

As a bonus here is a script that will remove the pictures that this places on your sheet so that you can test several times without having to select each picture one at a time to delete them:

```
Sub DeleteAllPics()
    Dim pic As Object
    For Each pic In ActiveSheet.Pictures
        pic.Delete
    Next pic
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You have the worksheet, so you don't have to use a range and set the cells that way.  Just set the cells of the worksheet directly

```
Dim Row As long
Dim Col As long

Set wks = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)

For Col = 1 to 10
    For Row = 1 To 100
        wks.Cells(Row, Col).Value = (Col - 1) * 100 + Row
    Next
Next
```

Comment: Not sure how to add this For Loop. When mine is setup with `For i = 1 to 100` and the `ctl.FaceId = i` and `rngInput.Cells(i).Value = i`

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a loop and nested loop, such that:

```
Dim i as Long, j as Long, k as Long
k = 0
For j = 1 to 3 Step 1
    For i = 1 to 100 Step 1
        'Something using Cells(i+k, j)
    Next i
    k = k + 100
Next j
```

Note that the row (i) is the 1 to 100 which occurs inside each column (j), so you will go 1 to 100, then switch column and go 1 to 100.  I only listed 3 columns in this example, but you can make it whatever you would like (1 = A, 2 = B, etc.).

The use of k is to increase by 100 for each column you move to, which is added to your row (i) as it loops 1 to 100.